# Why does this method only return values of 0 to a new array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am supposed to write a short program that takes 10 numbers, stores the values in an array, passes it to a method (`eliminateDuplicates()`) that creates a new array of only the unique values from the first array.

However, I am having trouble either initializing the `output` array, or making the `eliminateDuplicates()` method return the output array properly. The output array is always full of 0's and I cannot figure out why this is failing.

````
        java.util.Arrays.parallelSort(inputNumbers); //sorts the array in ascending order

        eliminateDuplicates(inputNumbers); //passes array to eliminateDuplicates method

        //display each unique value in output array
        System.out.print("The distinct numbers are ");
        for(int i = 0; i < outputNumbers.length; i++)
            System.out.print(outputNumbers[i] + " ");
    }

    public static int [] eliminateDuplicates(int[] list) {
        int[] outputNumbers = new int [list.length];
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            if(i == 0)              //compares each array value against preceding value
                outputNumbers[i] = list[i];     //only copies unique values to output array 
            else
            if(list[i] != list [i-1]) {
                outputNumbers[k] = list[i];
                k++;
            }
        return outputNumbers;```
````

Comment: Do you happen to have a static `outputNumbers` variable you forgot to include in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring the array returned by your method.

Change

```
eliminateDuplicates(inputNumbers);
```

to

```
int[] outputNumbers = eliminateDuplicates(inputNumbers);
```

P.S. your output array has the same length as the input array. Therefore, since you are eliminating duplicates, it may have some 0s as its last elements. If that's not what you want, you should create the output array only after you find out how many unique numbers the input array has.

Answer (score 0):

You have a *local* `outputNumbers` in `eliminateDuplicates` which you `return`. I assume you also have a redundant `static outputNumbers`. Option 1: Eliminate the local variable, change

```
int[] outputNumbers = new int [list.length];
```

to

```
outputNumbers = new int [list.length];
```

Option 2: Set `outputNumbers` on call (which is what I would likely do, and eliminate the `static` one)... Like,

```
int[] outputNumbers = eliminateDuplicates(inputNumbers);
```

Don't forget to remove the `static` one if you use option 2.